# Select multiple Dropdown-Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to select multiple values of select box? You may be forced to mark this as possible duplicate but before please consider this. What am i doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/xcy7e/gc5jn235/1/

```
$('#dd').val([1,2]);
console.log($('#dd').val()); // Will output "1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add attribute "multiple" to the select

```
<select id="dd" size="2" multiple>
```

Comment: Embarassing. Thanks! So is the size-Attribute a must-have too?

Comment: @xcy7e no, `size` is optional.